# Do the kotlin extension functions in com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx dispatch to Dispatchers.IO internally?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, android-billing

Reading the documentation for the billing client, there is a section entitled [Querying with Kotlin extensions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#querying_with_kotlin_extensions). The example shown includes a dispatch to `Dispatchers.IO` like this:

```
val productDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    billingClient.queryProductDetails(params.build())
}
```

The `withContext` is shown on other suspending functions as well. `queryProductDetails` in the ktx lib and the others are all suspending functions. Why do the docs include `withContext`? I can't imagine the purpose of making a suspending function that just blocked the thread, it should internally dispatch to `Dispatchers.IO` in my opinion, rendering the `withContext` calls in the example code superfluous.

Is my assessment correct, can I omit the `withContext` blocks without blocking the Main thread (assuming the calling context is on `Dispatchers.Main`)? I wasn't able to determine what it was doing with the debugger, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on the extension functions.

What I want to write is just:

```
val productDetailsResult = billingClient.queryProductDetails(params.build())
```

Comment: Yes, generally we shouldn't need to use `Dispatchers.IO` when invoking suspend functions. At least assuming the suspend function is implemented properly, so it never blocks. And by seeing they are only extensions over callback-based API, I suspect they in fact don't block.

Comment: When using the `withContext` function, you'll be using the `lifecycleScope.launch` coroutine to start the former. So the operations inside that `launch` block will wait until the `withContext` block completes, not the outer side i.e the MainThread won't be blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decompiled `Java` code of `queryProductDetails` extension function looks like the following:

```
   @Nullable
   @RecentlyNonNull
   public static final Object queryProductDetails(@RecentlyNonNull BillingClient $this$queryProductDetails, @RecentlyNonNull QueryProductDetailsParams params, @RecentlyNonNull Continuation $completion) {
      final CompletableDeferred var3 = CompletableDeferredKt.CompletableDeferred$default((Job)null, 1, (Object)null);
      ProductDetailsResponseListener var4 = new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
         public final void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List productDetailsList) {
            Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(billingResult, "billingResult");
            ProductDetailsResult var3x = new ProductDetailsResult(billingResult, productDetailsList);
            var3.complete(var3x);
         }
      };
      $this$queryProductDetails.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, var4);
      return var3.await($completion);
   }
```

We can see that it uses `queryProductDetailsAsync` under the hood, so it runs asynchronously. Therefore we can conclude that the call is not blocking and we don't need to wrap `billingClient.queryProductDetails(params.build())` into `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`:

```
val productDetailsResult = billingClient.queryProductDetails(params.build())
```