# Kotlin coroutines: suspended function works on first call but not subsequent calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines

apologies if this is trivial - I am new to Kotlin and coroutines (read [Elizarov etc.](https://elizarov.medium.com/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952))

I have an Activity that, in its onCreate(), needs to get a price from the Play Store. I wrote this:

```
...
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val pd = StoreHelper.getProductDetails(pp!!)
    val price = pd?.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.formattedPrice
    if (price != null) {
        buyNowBtn.text = getString(R.string.buy_price, price)
    } else {
        buyNowBtn.text = getString(R.string.buy_no_price)
    }
}
...
```

Then, the helper's getProductDetails() I copy-pasted from the docs (notice suspend):

```
suspend fun getProductDetails(PitchProductId: Long) : ProductDetails? {
    var pd: ProductDetails? = null
    val queryProductDetailsParams =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            ...
            .build()

    // leverage queryProductDetails Kotlin extension function
    val productDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        billingClient.queryProductDetails(queryProductDetailsParams)
    }
    if (productDetailsResult.productDetailsList?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        pd = productDetailsResult.productDetailsList!![0]
    }
    return pd
}
```

The problem: The Activity can request prices for different products. The first call works. But all subsequent calls don't: I get back a null. I bump the app and get the same thing again (first call works). Looks like I need to cancel something... Sorry, totally lost. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "subsequent calls"? Where / how are those calls made if the first call is made in `Activity.onCreate`? And how does `billingClient`? Isn't that where the `null` would originally be getting returned from?

Comment: Hey @BrianYencho, I was looking under the wrong street lamp. I was handling billing incorrectly, it wasn't the coroutines. I'd delete the question but people have already (kindly) responded. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the root cause! I think one thing you could do to wrap up this question if you'd like is to write an answer to it yourself (saying what you said here) and then accept as the correct answer. I believe I've seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your issue, but I think you are missing checking whether the query was successful. If you log the failure case, it will lead you toward a solution.

By the way, you don't need to use `withContext` with `queryProductDetails()`. I'm pretty sure that's a mistake in the documentation. [See here for explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562979/do-the-kotlin-extension-functions-in-com-android-billingclientbilling-ktx-dispa)

I haven't updated from version 4 to 5, so some of my variable and function names might be wrong in this example. Especially `productDetailsResult.result`--I'm just guessing at that. Can't find documentation on their extension functions online.

```
suspend fun getProductDetails(PitchProductId: Long) : ProductDetails? {
    val queryProductDetailsParams =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            ...
            .build()
    val productDetailsResult = billingClient.queryProductDetails(queryProductDetailsParams)

    if (productDetailsResult.result.responseCode != BillingResult.OK) {
        val resultList = productDetailsResult.productDetailsList.orEmpty()
        if (resultList.isNotEmpty() {
            return resultList.first()
        }
        Log.e("MyBilling", "Query product details result was OK but list was empty!")
        return null
    }
    Log.e("MyBilling", "Query product details result was: ${productDetailsResult.result.debugMessage}.")
    return null
}
```

Comment: Thanks 10-4. Confirming that removing the withContext works. Good thinking re printing out the return code (...). I get SERVICE_DISCONNECTED, so I reconnect and re-request recursively, and find myself in an infinite loop. I don't think it's the lib. It's my ignorant abuse of coroutines... I use deep links to get into the Activity that just ran the Play request, to ask for a different product. I think that I end up in the same activity, with the lifecycle still running and sort of "step on it"? Can I terminate it somehow after I get my result?

Comment: For the benefit of the community, adding below Tenfour's suggestion with working syntax for V 5.0

Comment: OK, I was reconnecting an already-connected client. Brilliant. Everything works fine. If someone with more points thinks this question can be deleted > I agree ;)

Answer (score -2):

Not an answer, just a working version of Tenfour's comment above ^

```
// continues from above...
val productDetailsResult =
    billingClient.queryProductDetails(queryProductDetailsParams)

Timber.d("PLAY: queryProductDetails rc=%d", productDetailsResult.billingResult.responseCode)
// https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponseCode

if (productDetailsResult.billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
    val resultList = productDetailsResult.productDetailsList.orEmpty()
    if (resultList.isNotEmpty()) {
        val pd = resultList.first()
        Timber.d(
            "PLAY: product name is %s at %s",
            pd.name,
            pd.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.formattedPrice ?: "0.00"
        )
        return pd
    }
}
else if ((productDetailsResult.billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED)) {
    Timber.d("PLAY: Service disconnected, reconnecting...")
    connect()
    return getProductDetails(pitchProductId)
}
...
// etc.
```